# Show an integral is finite

Tags: calculus, integration, exponentiation

EDITED: I am going a step up from what I had in the original post.

---

I am trying to show that the following integral is finite (I boiled down a much longer proof, and am just giving the part I got stuck on). It is known that $\int^\infty_{-\infty} k(x)|x|< \infty$, $\int^\infty_{-\infty} k(x) = c_1 < \infty$, and that $k(x)$ is an even function. Furthermore, it is also known that $k(x)=0$ when $|x|>1$.

$$\int^\infty_{-\infty}\int^\infty_{-\infty} k(x) \left (\frac{cos(\lambda x) - c_1}{\lambda^2} \right )  dx d\lambda $$

I originally tried using the identity:

$$sin^2(x) =\frac{1-cos(2x)}{2}$$

However that gave me,

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty \kappa(x) \frac{sin^2(\lambda x/2)}{\lambda^2} dx d\lambda + \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty \kappa(x) \frac{c_2}{\lambda^2} dx d\lambda$$

where $c_2+1 = c_1$ ($c_1$ is likely just a bit larger than 1). We can call these the first and second components.

The first component I used the identity $\forall c \in \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \int^\infty_{-\infty} \left ( \frac{\sin(x/c) }{x}\right )^2 dx \approx \frac{\pi}{|c|}$. I gathered that the first component was approximately equal to

$$\frac{\pi}{2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty \kappa(x) |x| dx d\lambda$$

However the second component escapes me.  Is there away to show that my original integral (first one above), is finite?

Comment: The _sense_ in which this integral needs to be finite depends on how your proof works. Please edit your question to show [what you were working on](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).

Comment: Updated to an earlier level in the problem, with more context on what I am trying to show